# Global regex matching stopping mid-string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract groups of numbers from a string.
These numbers can either be on their own or as a range in the format `\d+ - \d+`, while the range indicator between the two numbers can vary and the numbers can either have the prefix `M-` or `STR` . These groups can occur 1 to n times in a given string, but the matching should stop if a group is followed by any character that is not a number, whitespace or one of the prefixes mentioned above, even if further numbers can be found afterwards.

As an example, the following lines

```
01
05,07
05, 7
M-01, M-12
311,STR 02
M-56
STR 17
01 - Random String 25-31 Random other string
M-04 Random String 01
M-17,3,148,14 to 31
M-17,3,STR 148,14 to 31 - Random String
M-17,3,148,14- 31 Random, String 02 Random, other string
STR 17,3,12 to 18, 148 ,M-14- 31 : Random String 02
```

Should return

```
01
05;07
05;7
01;12
311;02
56
17
01
04
17;3;148;14 to 31
17;3;148;14 to 31
17;3;148;14- 31
17;3;12 to 18;148;14- 31
```

I'm using javascript and can almost get a correct result by running

```
var pattern = /(\d+)\s?(?:-|~|to)?\s?(\d+)?/ig
while (result = pattern.exec(line)) {console.log(result)}
```

but I can't figure out how to not match numbers after the first string, i.e. `M-17,3,148,14 to 31 - Random string 46 Random string` would return the values `17;3;148;14 to 31;46`, while 46 should not be matched.

I'm not really concerned over the format of the results since I'm sanitizing them anyway atferwards, so it doesn't matter if `'03 '` comes back as `'03'` or `'03 '`. This is also true for number ranges, `15 - 17` can either be returned as `15 - 17` or, like in the example above, use capturing groups to determine the upper and lower bound, but I still need be able to tell if two numbers are separate or a range, so `5,8,10-12` can't be returned as `5;8;10;12`.

My ultimate goal is to extract all possible values in each line. After I extracted all number ranges, I loop through each result to get all possible values, e.g. 5,8,10-12 would become 5;8;10;11;12.

If it is somehow possible, and this is purely optional, I'd also like to preserve the string after the last number range, e.g. `STR 14, 23 Some String 18 Some other string` should return in `14;23` and separately `Some String 18 Some other string`.

I'd be grateful if anybody has an idea on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt.

```js
[
    '01',
    '05,07',
    '05, 7',
    'M-01, M-12',
    '311,STR 02',
    'M-56',
    'STR 17',
    '01 - Random String 25-31 Random other string',
    'M-04 Random String 01',
    'M-17,3,148,14 to 31',
    'M-17,3,STR 148,14 to 31 - Random String',
    'M-17,3,148,14- 31 Random, String 02 Random, other string',
    'STR 17,3,12 to 18, 148 ,M-14- 31 : Random String 02',
    '14 ~ 16',
    'Random String 15',
    '1to3',
    'M-01 to STR 6',
    '17 56'
].forEach(function(str) {
    var rangeRe = /(?:\s*,\s*)(?:M-|STR )?(\d+)(?:\s*(?:-|~|to)\s*(\d+))?/g,
        ranges = [],
        lastIndex = 1,
        match;

    str = ',' + str;

    while (match = rangeRe.exec(str)) {
        // Push a lower and upper bound onto the list of ranges
        ranges.push([+match[1], +(match[2] || match[1])]);

        lastIndex = rangeRe.lastIndex;
    }

    // Log the original string, the ranges and the remainder
    console.log([
       str.slice(1),
       ranges.map(function(pair) {
           return pair[0] + '-' + pair[1];
       }).join(' ; '),
       str.slice(lastIndex)
    ]);
});
```

Here are the rules I've followed:

- Numbers consists of consecutive digits.
- A range consists of either a single number or a pair of numbers.
- If a range features a pair they can be separated by `-`, `~` or `to`, plus arbitrary whitespace either side the separator.
- A range (note range, not number) can be prefixed by `M-` or `STR`. No extra whitespace is permitted between the prefix and the range.
- Ranges are separated by `,` plus arbitrary whitespace either side of the `,`.

Each range is parsed into an array pair consisting of the lower and upper bound. For a single-number range the same value is used for both bounds.

I've used the statefulness of `exec`. Each iteration of the loop begins matching where the previous match left off. The `lastIndex` is tracked so that we can generate the remaining 'random string' at the end.

I add a `,` out the front of the string before I start. This allows the RegExp to assume that all ranges start with a `,`, avoiding the need for a special case of the first range.

A key difference from some of the RegExps that you posted was that I made the entire 'range separator and upper bound' section optional as a unit, rather than making them individually optional. The result of this is that an input like `17 56` would be treat the `56` as the 'random string' and not as an upper bound. The range would be treated as 17-17.

Comment: This works incredibly well. Much better than my original solution. Thanks a lot for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

So, after getting a coffee I think I figured out a something close to a solution:

```
function extractNumbers(line){
    var str = line.replace(/(?:M-\s?|STR )(\d+)/ig,'$1')
    var rightpart = str.match(/([a-x].*)/i)
    var leftpart = str.replace(rightpart[1],'')
    var pattern = /(\d+)\s?(?:-|~|to)?\s?(\d+)?/ig
    while (result = pattern.exec(leftpart)) {console.log(result)}
    console.log(rightpart[1])
}
```

This function outputs all number ranges and then the rest of the string to the console. There are chances for false positives because it first replaces all occurrences of M- and STR followed by a number, even if they occur in the right part of the string. The chances of this exact sequence of characters occurring in the right part are probably small, but still..

If anybody has an answer to the original question or an idea on how to eliminate the chance for false positives, I would love to see it.